# Handling DataTemplate element changes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a drop down combo box which contains a list of check boxes. The list is created dynamically. I need a clean way to handle the check box changes.

WPF:

```
        <ComboBox Margin="0,10,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Column="3" x:Name="cb_Filters" SelectionChanged="Cb_Filters_SelectionChanged" MaxDropDownHeight="250" >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Content="{Binding FilterOption}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

CODE

```
public class Filters {
            public Filters()
            {   }

            public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
            public string FilterOption { get; set; }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Filters> ListOfFilters = new ObservableCollection<Filters>
        {
            new Filters {IsSelected = true, FilterOption = "Suppliers"}
        };

        CollectionView collectionView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ListOfFilters);
        cb_Filters.ItemsSource = collectionView;
        TextSearch.SetTextPath(cb_Filters, "FilterOption");
```

My way is to create a tag for the element, and find it using VisualTreeHelper, however I'm not sure if there is any easier/cleaner way to perform this.

Thank you

Comment: A clean way would be to attach a `ICommand` to the `CheckBox.Command` property, which would trigger the filtering. Since `CheckBox` derives from `ToggleButton` they have the same members. So you could alternatively subscribe to the `CheckBox.Checked` and `CheckBox.Unchecked` events. Using the `VisualTreeHelper` to find the check boxes is definitely not a good solution. You don't need to get the `CollectionView`, you can set the `ObservableCollection` directly to the `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Clean way is to use MvvM. Your element(view model) would hold all of selected values. problem solved.